# Is training a neural network with same training examples bad practice?

Tags: neural-network

Training a neural network where N training examples contains same attributes and classification. E.g :

Training example1 = [1,1,1,1] , classification = [1]

Training example2 = [1,1,1,1] , classification = [1]

It's wasting training time training with 'Training example2' as it will not contribute to the overall quality of the neural network ?

Comment: The training set should be an indication of the data the network will classify post training. If you know that some of the input signals you will be classifying appear more often that others, it is good practice to wean the network more to these data entries. In other words, it might not be wasteful

Comment: @jorgenkg can you elaborate on 'wean the network more to these data entries' , do you mean use an extra bias layer ?

Comment: Lets say the real data you will be classifying are `[a, a, a, a, b, c]`. In other words, a specific classification pattern is more likely to appear in the real world data. Then you would like the network to be more likely to classify pattern `a`. However, if your real world data is similar to `[a, a, b, b, c, c]`, then the training set should also contain approx. the same ratio between the various input patterns. (When I use the term input patterns, I'm refering to the set of input vectors that should be classified as the same class).

Comment: By presenting more input vectors that should be classified as class `a` during training, you are essentially gearing the network towards classifying a "suprising" input vector as `a` during testing.

Comment: @jorgenkg what controls this 'gearing' ? the cost function ?

Comment: No, the number of similar input vectors in the training set. Having `[a, a, a, b]` in the training set, incites the learning process to output `a` rather than `b` during testing. Thereby geared the network towards outputing `a`.

Comment: @jorgenkg thanks,  can you explain the math behind 'geared' ? The learning process is the cost function which is what back propogation utilises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if it doesn't harm your learning process a lot - would left them in your training set. The reason behind this is stated in the following points :

1. Usually - the process of learning of a neural network has it probability theory interpretation. You are learning some conditional distribiution `P(y|x)`. In this case it's obvious that the more learning examples you have, the more accurate approximation you will have.
2. Very often your data hasn't a functional form where `y = f(x)`. In this case you need to deal with uncertainty. In this case the more examples you have - the more sure you are about your predictions.
3. In some comments someone said that if e.g. every example occurs twice in dataset then this might be redundant. But checking if your data comes from such distribiution is either obvious or too computationally costly to check. So you shouldn't care about this.

Answer (score 0):

One example where the best practice is to use common training examples less frequently is in word2vec. See this link for more information.

https://www.quora.com/How-does-sub-sampling-of-frequent-words-work-in-the-context-of-Word2Vec